# How to get the MLE of counts in a $2 \times 2$ table

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

I am a student who just starts to learn about statistics. I have some data as below:

- Like apple and like banana: $N_{11}$
- Like apple but dislike banana: $N_{10}$
- Dislike apple but like banana: $N_{01}$
- Dislike apple and dislike banana: $N_{00}$

Now I am trying to find the MLE for the joint distributions of each two among these four preferences. Let $x_1 \in$ {0,1} represents the `like and dislike` of apple and $x_2 \in$ {0,1} represents the same thing for banana. For example, P($x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 1$) represents the joint distribution of  `Like apple and like banana`.

Forgive me if this is a very stupid question, but I am not sure what is the parameter here that we need to control in order to find the maximum likelihood estimation. Hence I cant find the likelihood function for the joint distribution. Please give me some guidance on how to further explore this problem.

**UPDATE**

I have asked the tutor for more information about building a model for such variables. He mentioned about using the re-parameterisation trick:
$$
N_{kl} = \frac{e^{\eta_{kl}}}{\sum_{k=0,l=0}^{1,1}e^{\eta_{kl}}}
$$

But I am not sure how to use this to build a model. Since in my understanding, a model of the joint probability of $P(x_1 = 1, x_2 = 1)$ is simply the number of people who like both fruits divided by the number of sample: $\frac{N_{11}}{N_{11} + N_{10} + N_{01} + N_{00}}$. But in this case what is the random variable I need to focus on?

Comment: You need to *write down a model* for the random variables (presumably the counts in this case); we can't tell you your model. However if you believe the probabilities are constant and the variables independent, then the grand total will be fixed at the number of people asked, $n$.  A general model could be conceived as multinomial but how you parameterize this will depend on what you're interested in doing - if you want to write the probabilities as a loglinear model, for example, you could write each cell's probability as function of an "apple" effect, a "banana" effect and an interaction ...

Comment: ... (with not all effects present in all cells, naturally). You could use dummies to write the whole thing in one model. However, if you choose to condition on the margins then any one cell of the four would be hypergeometric (and the other three would then be fixed given that one).

Comment: @Glen_b Many thanks to the suggestions. I have tried to write a model for the joint probability distribution but still confused what should a `model` consists of. Could you please have a look on my update in the post and give me some more suggestions on this?

Comment: Consider: If you knew what the probability of falling into any of the cells would be ($p_{ij}$), how would the set of four counts be distributed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is most likely much simpler than your tutor suggests.  If $N_{11},N_{10}, N_{01}, N_{00}$ is all the data you have, then you can most likely will make simplifying assumptions that use a multinomial or poisson formulation.  Let $n=N_{11}+N_{10}+N_{01}+N_{00}$.  In the multinomial formulation, let $p_{11}$ represent the probability a subject from the population likes apples and bananas, defining other parameters for the other settings.  Thus you wish to find the MLE of $p_{11},p_{10}, p_{01}, p_{00}$ when $(N_{11},N_{10}, N_{01}, N_{00}) \sim Multinomial(n,(p_{11},p_{10}, p_{01}, p_{00}))$, where $\sum_{0=1}^1\sum_{j=0}^1 p_{ij} =1$.  Since $n$ is treated as known, the only parameters are $(p_{11},p_{10}, p_{01}, p_{00})$.  To find these MLEs we maximize this model's log-likelihood (the logarithm of the probability mass function of $(N_{11},N_{10}, N_{01}, N_{00})$.  This log-likelihood, up to an additive constant, is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
l\left(p_{11},p_{10}, p_{01}, p_{00}|N_{11},N_{10}, N_{01}, N_{00}\right)= \sum_{0=1}^1\sum_{j=0}^1 N_{ij} \log \left(p_{ij}\right) \quad \mbox{subject to} \quad \sum_{0=1}^1\sum_{j=0}^1 p_{ij} =1.
\end{eqnarray*}

Equivalently, we can let $N_{ij} \overset{i.i.d.}{\sim} Poisson(n \lambda_{ij})$ for $i,j \in \{0,1\}$.  In this case, no restriction needs to be placed on $\sum_{0=1}^1\sum_{j=0}^1 \lambda_{ij}$.   Since $n$ is treated as known, the only parameters are $\lambda_{11},\lambda_{10}, \lambda_{01}, \lambda_{00})$.  To find these MLEs we maximize this model's log-likelihood (the logarithm of the probability mass function of $(N_{11},N_{10}, N_{01}, N_{00})$. This log-likelihood, up to an additive constant, is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
l\left(\lambda_{11},\lambda_{10}, \lambda_{01}, \lambda_{00}|N_{11},N_{10}, N_{01}, N_{00}\right)= \sum_{0=1}^1\sum_{j=0}^1 N_{ij} \log \left(\lambda_{ij}\right) - n\sum_{0=1}^1\sum_{j=0}^1 \lambda_{ij}.
\end{eqnarray*}

There is no novelty in finding the MLEs of discrete data as compared to continuous data in this case since what is important is whether the parameters are continuous or discrete.  If one wishes to find the MLE of a discrete parameter, then calculus arguments do not work, but one usually compares say $X$ with $X+1$, depending on the discretiziation.